# PyQt: How to get QTableWidgetItem contents while item is being edited?

Tags: pyqt4, qt-signals, qtablewidgetitem

In the end, the problem I'm trying to solve is that of someone editing a field in a `QTableWidget` and then clicking "OK" before hitting the enter key or changing focus out of the table cell.

Default behavior seems to be to ignore this cell, as it hasn't "committed".

Here's a quick example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import pprint
from PyQt4 import QtCore,QtGui

class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(Dialog,self).__init__(parent)

        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget(5,2)

        button_box = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        button_box.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        button_box.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        layout.addWidget(button_box)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def accept(self):
        ret = {}
        for i in range(self.table.rowCount()):  
            k = self.table.item(i,0)
            v = self.table.item(i,1)
            if not k:
                continue
            if k.text().isEmpty():
                continue
            if not v:
                v = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("")
            ret[str(k.text())] = str(v.text())

        pprint.pprint(ret)


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = Dialog()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In this example, if I enter `a` in the first cell then `b` in the second cell; then click "OK" without first hitting the enter key or changing focus, I will see printed:

`{'a': ''}`

When I want to see:

`{'a': 'b'}`

An idea I had was to treat the cell like a QLineEdit and use textChanged to see when the user was typing, and then, behind the scenes, setItem of the cell with each key stroke -- the idea being that the data in the cell is always up to date.  I attempted this by using `QStyledItemDelegate` (below) so that it edits like a QLineEdit (which has a textChanged signal).  This works to some degree, as I can print out the changes from the delegate itself, but I can't seem to get the textChanged signal anywhere it's useful (in other words, the dialog doesn't see this, therefore it can't setItem in the table).

```
class LineEditDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    textChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QtGui.QLineEdit(parent)
        editor.textChanged.connect(self.textChanged)
        return editor
```

But that's not doing the trick.

I also tried emitting a commitData signal when the QLineEdit's textChanged fires, but that also has not helped.

Is there a way to get cell contents while the cell is still being edited?

Comment: Do you need the line `textChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)`? You don't need to redefine that signal if it already exists on the line edit object.

Comment: If you want to attach the line edit's `textChanged` signal to something meaningful you could pass a function reference to `LineEditDelegate` and then allow the editor connect to that, e.g. `editor.textChanged.connect(self.some_external_func)`.

Comment: Although that said there's probably a lot simpler way to do all this...

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue (pyqt4, linux opensuse). I enter `b` in the second cell, and then directly click on "OK", and it prints `{'a': 'b'}`. For me the cell being edited is not ignored, but indeed "committed".

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem, either. Please state the platform you are testing on, and the exact versions of Qt and PyQt you are using.

Comment: Interesting that others are seeing different behavior.  
I'm running PyQt 4.8.6, python 2.6.9, OS X 10.9.

Comment: I neglected to mention that I'm also running Qt 4.8.6.

Comment: @BrianK. Can't reproduce using Python 2.6.9, PyQt 4.8.6, Qt 4.8.7 on Linux. This is probably a platform-related issue. Presumably, focus-handling works differently on OSX.